# Hover opacity CSS Minimum image size

Tags: css, hover, opacity

I am using the below CSS to create a hover opacity for images. I'd like to be able to set a minimum allowance so only images of a certain size take on the opacity.

Ex. My 225x225 images are correctly taking on the opacity, but so is my large header image. I only want images 225x225 and below to take on opacity when hovered over, not all.

```
img {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
/* For IE8 and earlier */
}

 img:hover {
opacity: .8;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use a class for this not a basic selector like `img`.

Comment: @Paulie_D he would need to mark each new image smaller than 225x225.  Also when you would be working with dynamic content it would never work.

Comment: I can't see your HTML, so I'm just guessing, but is there no way you can differentiate your 225x225 images from the other images? Is the header inside a different container or something? would `:nth-child` be an option?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use media queries on a single element, so you are left to use JavaScript here. There are new CSS rules in the making for this, but it's not reliable to use them at this point.

What you could do is add a listener the img tags with jQuery and review the CSS on page-load. If the image's size does not meet your requirements towards the opacity level, you could cap it.

Answer (score 0):

As Allendar pointed out in his answer; use JavaScript for this, however if JavaScript isn't an option then you'll have to make a class and add that CSS class to each element you want to have the opacity effect on hover.

Comment: As I commented on Paulie_D's comment; if the OP uses dynamic code that can switch on image sizes, binding classes isn't reliable enough. You could only achieve that by analyzing your image's dimensions with your server-side script before you serve them.